# Asserts in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a doubt about unit tests and asserts. If I have a certain object with many attributes (say, about 30), and for a test I only care about validating that 2 fields of the object change correctly when calling the method I am testing, is it necessary to validate the values of all the attributes?

On the other hand, how should I handle the equals of objects? Since when using Mockito, if I want to mock a method, I have to tell it that when the method is called with certain parameters, it should return a certain object. Among the parameters of the method I have an object, so I would have to define equals with all the fields of the object (although I think this would not be correct) or define some kind of special comparator for that case.

Also if I define a special comparator, should I compare every field or only fields I care about? If i compare only some fields, could it be a problem when I add a field? (because in this case the test would compile and work but is not validating everything it should)

Specifically, I would like to know:

- Is it necessary to validate all attributes of an object in a unit test?
- How can I handle the equals of objects in unit tests with Mockito?

Comment: What you feel it is necessary to test is entirely up to you. There's no law that says complete code coverage is required.  There's no law that says complete code coverage pays back the time spent on it.

Comment: So, what you want to do, is `object.doTheOperation(); assertEquals(expected1, object.getAttribute1()); assertEquals(expected2, object.getAttribute2());` Then, just do that. There is no need for mocking and no need to deal with unrelated attributes.

Comment: BTW we do not know your objects, its attributes, its usage, ... so we hardly can know what must be tested and what not

Answer (score 0):

Long story short - you should verify only the attributes you care about.

From an assertion perspective, this means you should assert them explicitly:

```java
assertEquals("expected value", myObject.getSomeAttribute());
assertEquals("other expected value", myObejct.getAnotherAttribute());
```

From a mocking perspective, you should mock the expectation of those attributes:

```java
when(myObject.methodToMock(argThat(c -> c.getSomeAttribute().equals("something"))))
   .thenRetrun("mocked result");
```